# Using css/js, hide <h2> in a div when hovered over

Tags: javascript, html, css

What I've tried (css):

```
div:hover #h2 {
  color: transparent; 
}
```

I want to hide text in a `div` like this:

```
<div>
  <h2>text</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: div:hover #h2{
   display:none;
    }

Comment: Your selector is wrong `div:hover h2 {...}`

Comment: `div:hover h2 { color: transparent;}`

Comment: be careful that color:transfer not working in all browsers like old IEs

Answer (score 7):

You should remove the `#`:

```
div:hover h2 {
    color: transparent; 
}
```

A `#` indicates an id instead of a tag name (so you were selecting `id="h2"`).

Answer (score 2):

this will hide H2 tag on DIV hover

```
div:hover h2{
    display: none; 
}
```

if you need fix height in your DIV you can use this one:

```
div:hover h2{
    visibility: hidden; 
}
```

**UPDATE:**
duo to questioner comment, if you want to use a specific id, do like this:

```
<div id="spdiv"><h2>message</h2></div>
```

and in css

```
#spdiv:hover h2{
    display: none; 
}
```

using `#` helps you to specify element id

Comment: what would i do to apply this only to a particular div id

Comment: @rabbitforpm I'll update the answer due to your comment, for adding particular id, please check that